# How to compute the total concave surface area on a 3D binary mask in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, convex-hull, concave-hull

I have a 3D binary mask (from a Dicom image) with one object in it.
I want to calculate the **total concave surface area** and also the **total convex surface area** of the object in it. For the `total convex surface area`, I have used this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25747918/how-to-calculate-the-area-by-triangulating-a-3d-object-in-matlab), which its code in Matlab is as follows:

```
FV = isosurface(BW_Img, 0.5); % BW_Img with dimensions 28x23x18
V = FV.vertices;
F = FV.faces;
A = V(F(:, 2), :) - V(F(:, 1), :);
B = V(F(:, 3), :) - V(F(:, 1), :);
C = cross(A, B, 2);
Convex_surf_area_3D = 1/2 * sum(sqrt(sum(C.^2, 2)));
```

For the `total concave surface area`, I have seen this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25487554/matlab-calculate-volume-of-concave-polyhedron-from-set-of-scattered-3d-points), but I don't know how to use it (`alphaShape`) on the 3D binary mask:

```
shp = alphaShape(BW_Img);
concave_surf_area_3D = volume(shp);  % or : concave_surf_area_3D = surfaceArea(shp); 

% Error using alphaShape: The input points must be 2D or 3D coordinates in numpoints-by-ndim format.
```

If the above code is my answer, How to set its inputs argument for my 3D binary mask?

else, How to compute the `total concave surface area` on the 3D binary mask in Matlab?

Comment: alphashape requires points, not a mask. Extract the locations of the edge of your mask

Comment: Is this correct?  `bwIm = logical(BW_Img);  bwIm_dist = bwdist(1-bwIm);  Surf = bwIm - (bwIm_dist > 1.5); % To getting the surface. [pX, pY, pZ] = ind2sub(size(bwIm),find(Surf)); Points_array = [pX, pY, pZ];                                                  shp = alphaShape(Points_array);  concave_surf_area_3D = volume(shp);`

Comment: I don't know, you have tried it, is it correct?

Comment: @AnderBiguri : Yes.

Comment: Fantastic! then feel free to answer your own question  with the solution!